# Ensure a component takes up all available space within a SplitPane

Tags: javafx-2

I've got a (horizontal) split pane, with a tabbed pane as the left component. I want to ensure that the content of each tab takes up all available space when the divider of the split pane is resized, but I'm a bit confused as to what I should be binding to what. Any tips?

Thanks,

Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

did you try anything?

Because you described default behavior for most cases. Put any layout manager other from `Pane` and `Group` inside `SplitPane` and they will try to take all available space for them.